# Angular JS - reload entire Page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an angular application and I want to load the entire page template after the user logs in

Here is my login code

```
        $scope.login = function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        Auth.login({
            username: $scope.username,
            password: $scope.password,
            rememberMe: $scope.rememberMe
        }).then(function () {
            $scope.authenticationError = false;
            if ($rootScope.previousStateName === 'register') {
                $state.go('home');
            } else {
                 $location.path("dashboard");
                }
        }).catch(function () {
            $scope.authenticationError = true;

        });
    };
```

When I navigate to the dashboard - I had hoped that all my controllers would load again but they dont
Specifically I want to reload my header controller so the users name and image appears on screen - it is only reloaded when I press F5

Is there anyway to **force a reload of controllers** when a user is successful in the login?

Cheers
Damien

**index.html code with javascript imports**

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
        <title>Page</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Responsive Admin Web App">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,400,600,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <!-- Needs images, font... therefore can not be part of main.css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/themify-icons/themify-icons.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jsLibs/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jsLibs/weather-icons/css/weather-icons.min.css">
        <!-- end Needs images -->


            <!-- build:css({.tmp,client}) styles/main.css -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/ui.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
            <!-- endbuild -->

    </head>
    <body data-ng-app="app"
          id="app"
          class="app"
          data-custom-page 
          data-off-canvas-nav
          data-ng-controller="AppCtrl"
          data-ng-class=" {'layout-boxed': admin.layout === 'boxed'} "
          >
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <div class="lt-ie9-bg">
                <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser.</p>
                <p>Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
            </div>
        <![endif]-->

        <section data-ng-include=" 'views/header.html' "
                 id="header"
                 class="header-container "
                 data-ng-class="{ 'header-fixed': admin.fixedHeader,
                                  'bg-white': ['11','12','13','14','15','16','21'].indexOf(admin.skin) >= 0,
                                  'bg-dark': admin.skin === '31',
                                  'bg-primary': ['22','32'].indexOf(admin.skin) >= 0,
                                  'bg-success': ['23','33'].indexOf(admin.skin) >= 0,
                                  'bg-info-alt': ['24','34'].indexOf(admin.skin) >= 0,
                                  'bg-warning': ['25','35'].indexOf(admin.skin) >= 0,
                                  'bg-danger': ['26','36'].indexOf(admin.skin) >= 0
                 }"></section>

        <div class="main-container">
            <aside data-ng-include=" 'views/sidebar.html' "
                   id="nav-container"
                   class="nav-container"
                   data-ng-class="{ 'nav-fixed': admin.fixedSidebar,
                                    'nav-horizontal': admin.menu === 'horizontal',
                                    'nav-vertical': admin.menu === 'vertical',
                                    'bg-white': ['31','32','33','34','35','36'].indexOf(admin.skin) >= 0,
                                    'bg-dark': ['31','32','33','34','35','36'].indexOf(admin.skin) < 0
                   }">
            </aside>

            <div id="content" class="content-container">
                <section data-ng-view
                         class="view-container {{admin.pageTransition.class}}"></section>
            </div>
        </div>




        <!-- endbuild -->
    </body>
</html>

    enter code here
```

Comment: The point of angular is that the whole page doesn't reload, you want header, body and footer templates and have each reload as needed. The main page, running the angular app IMO, should always remain loaded.

Comment: thats the problem for me. I have a main page. The login screen shows full screen and all other controllers are loaded. But the header controller needs to access a protected endpoint to get user details. This can only be done after the successful login. Hope that makes sense

Comment: Assuming you are using templetes, can you edit your question to include what your main page code is? It would be helpful.

Comment: Just updated my question there - hope that helps

Comment: Ah, and see what I was saying is I think you want to use ng-view. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView

Comment: Instead of using strings in your `ng-includes`  use Angular expressions. Then you change them from your controller to kick the `ng-include` to reload. `ng-view` would work also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `reload: true`. This will execute your controller logic again.

> reload v0.2.5 Boolean (default false), If true will force transition
>   even if the state or params have not changed, aka a reload of the same
>   state. It differs from reloadOnSearch because you'd use this when you
>   want to force a reload when everything is the same, including search
>   params.

```
$state.go('home', toParams, { reload: true });
```

Check out the [quick ref docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options) for more information

Comment: I was just looking at my template and its code - it doesnt use states at the minute. Would it be hard to integrate in states to existing angular code?

Comment: hm, I only assumed your application was wired for ui-router once I saw you were calling `$state.go()` in your code. That's an up in the air question and I could't answer it for you - it depends greatly on your current app architecture, how far along you are, manpower etc. As myself speaking, I'd go ui-router, no doubt - but that'll be for you to decide. If you do make the leap forward, this answer would be a way to reload a state and accomplish what you are trying.

Comment: thanks scniro - yea that shouldnt have been in there sorry - just realise that. I think I may try to integrate in the ui-router - would I be correct in saying then that I wouldnt need to maintain a file full of routes and I can have independent roles for each route?

Comment: no worries - if you're early on with this, I'd advise to make the investment in learning ui-router - you'll thank yourself later (I went through the exact same)

Comment: cool ill take that advise onboard. Can you recommend any good resources for learning it?

Comment: absolutely, check out [this pluralsight tutorial](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/angular-routing-in-depth). If you don't have an account, there's a [free trial](https://app.pluralsight.com/a/subscribe/step1?isTrial=true&sku=IND-M-STD&v=a) option!

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree with Drazisil, you could use [angular-ui/ui-router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router) `$state.reload()`. Inject $scope in your controller and then create a method to reload.

```
$scope.reload = function() {
    $state.reload();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for all your suggestions - some really good points

I was fit to get around it by using   $scope.$watch on a variable that I set on successful login